# Find specific field in array by last date and updating it

Tags: mongodb

I have the document below, and I want to update in exams, the last exam with status "started" (according to date), I need to add to "done" another number

```
{
"_id": ObjectID("5d2a371cec7eaf00119df614"),
"firstname": "Laura",
"lastname": "Warriner",
"image": "2019-07-14t05:25:23.352z_13.jpg",
"exams": [
    {
        "examId": "Ba6apmRmz",
        "name": "general",
        "language": "es",
        "version": 2,
        "testId": "2000",
        "status": [
            {
                "status": "created",
                "date": ISODate("2019-09-08T11:49:42.124Z")
            },
            {
                "status": "started",
                "date": ISODate("2019-09-08T11:55:09.873Z"),
                "done": [1]
            },
            {
                "status": "started",
                "date": ISODate("2019-09-09T12:01:57.886Z"),
                "done": [2,3]
            },
            {
                "status": "completed",
                "date": ISODate("2019-09-09T12:01:57.886Z")
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a little complex.   Can you show use a sample input doc that has more than one exam in the `exams` array and what you want the end result document to look like, especially the "another number" thing?

Comment: @Buzz Moschetti thank for your answer.
I solved this using javascript, find the status I wanted, updating it. and then updating status array.